# Evaluate powers in fraction

Tags: contest-math

This is abstracted from 2007 British Mathematical Olympiad Question 1.I wish to practice mathematics olympiad question for the upcoming Singapore Mathematics Olympiad Secondary 2 (Grade 8).

> Find the value of $$\frac {1^4+2007^4+2008^4} {1^2+2007^2+2008^2}.$$

Note that calculators are **NOT** allowed to use and working **MUST** be provided.

For some reason,my brain immediately thought the answer is $2008\times2007+1$

I do not know if this is wrong or right.In the first place,I do not know how to begin other then knowing that $1^n$ is still 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In math contests you more often than not encounter a problem you don't know how to deal with right away. My go-to approach is then to experiment. 
Testing how the land lies with smaller values of parameters may lead to something (if there is a cumbersome looking parameter in the problem).

Here the year $2007$ kinda sticks out. So let's see what happens, if we just look at
$$
f(n)=\frac{1+n^4+(n+1)^4}{1+n^2+(n+1)^2}.
$$
Pencil+paper and/or mental arithmetic gives
$$
f(1)=\frac{1+1+16}{1+1+4}=3,\quad f(2)=\frac{1+16+81}{1+4+9}=7.
$$
While not conclusive, this does raise the suspicion that the answer may be an integer, doesn't it? Let's expand
$$
f(n)=\frac{2+4n+6n^2+4n^3+2n^4}{2+2n+2n^2}=\frac{1+2n+3n^2+2n^3+n^4}{1+n+n^2}=\frac{p(n)}{q(n)}.
$$
Hmmm? Doesn't look very clean (ok, we could just crank out long division of polynomials at this point, but bear with me for a moment)?! Let's repeat the exercise and plug in some numbers.
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(1)&=1+2+3+2+1=9,&q(1)&=3,\\
p(2)&=1+4+12+16+16=49,&q(2)&=1+2+4=7,\\
p(3)&=\cdots=169,&q(3)&=13.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now our pattern recognition algorithm will kick in. It sure looks like $p(n)$ could be $q(n)^2$. Let's try and prove that's the case
$$
q(n)^2=(1+n+n^2)^2=(1+n+n^2)+n(1+n+n^2)+n^2(1+n+n^2)=\cdots=p(n).
$$
We have a winner!

---

I'm not implying that this is *the* way to solve this specific problem. It is just a route that occured to me. Don't know if I would have come up with this in grade 8? Can't go back in time. Experimenting did show me the way with a couple of IMO problems back in the day. The path is not straight and narrow - you find your own!

Comment: I was in dilemma whether I should write $2007$ as $(2008 - 1)$ or $2008$ as $(2007  + 1)$. But I like the identity you got here. +1 for it.

Comment: This is quite late but you can divide that polynomial and get a clean cut polynomial.

Comment: Yes, you can @IanLimarta - I even said so. I don't know whether those contestants are familiar with polynomial (long) division? The contestants probably are, but I was trying to lead up to it even in case they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Write $2007$ as $(2008 - 1)$ in both numerator and denominator and expand them using binomial theorem to get:

$\frac{1^4 + 1^2 * 2008^2 + 2008^4}{1^2 + 1*2008 + 2008^2} = 1^2 - 1*2008 + 2008^2 = 1 + 2007*2008$

[using identity $(a^4 + a^2b^2 + b^4) = (a^2 + ab + b^2)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$]